# What new stuff came out in the last 2-3 Month

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

I didnt use Blender for a couple Month what have i missed ? some cool addons good features ? tell me.

Comment: This would be better in chat or on Blender Artists. It is off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes
You can read this documentation! All the new stuff since 2.57a that has been release is visible here! If you are interested in new addons, look for new resources in blenderartists.org;)